# eBay XML Trading API returns Base64 response instead of XML

Tags: xml, ebay-api

When I call Trading XML API sometimes it returns invalid response with different structure. This is happening for all API calls occasionally.

> Example:
>   section : Trading Api
>   type : xml
>   call : GetSessionID

**Input**
[image: my XML body]

**Invalid Output**
[image: invalid output]

**expected output**
[image: expected output]

**my questions are**

1. what does this output mean?
2. why is this happening?
3. how to get rid of this?

Comment: Don't post screenshots of text, copy/paste the _actual text_ into your post and format as code.  Did you decode the base64 value in the response to see what it contains?

Comment: i tried to add code. but i got validation error from stackoverflow. so i added images

Answer (score 0):

i have noticed that the response header has content-type to 'application/xml; charset=UTF-8'.

The result came were binary-to-text encoded. so i tried on base-64 decoding and finally got the result XML.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<eBay>
<EBayTime>2017-02-03 07:00:09</EBayTime>
<Errors>
<Error>
<Code>10007</Code> 
<ErrorClass>SystemError</ErrorClass>
<SeverityCode>1</SeverityCode>
<Severity>SeriousError</Severity>
<Line>0</Line>
<Column>0</Column>
<ShortMessage>
<![CDATA[ Internal error to the application ]]></ShortMessage></Error></Errors>
</eBay>
```

the error means that it is SystemError from ebay side.